# Set two imageview background alpha only one success

Tags: android, background, imageview

I have two `ImageView` and one `Button` in xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroud_msg_notify"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroud_msg_notify"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline" />
```

[image: design]

In my activity,I do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_image_view);
    final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    final ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
            imageView2.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
        }
    });
}
```

But only imageView1 background alpha changed,when first set imageview2,only imageview2 background changed. So I copy background file and set two imageview respectively.Two imageview all changed,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is they share the same `Drawable` for each of their backgrounds. Calling the [mutate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()) method of Drawable will help you here:

```
//Affects only the first one because mutate was called first.
imageView1.getBackground().mutate().setAlpha(100);
```

Read this for learning about mutating drawables:
http://www.curious-creature.com/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/